# Pushing existing project to github removed existing readme file

Tags: git, github

As far as I understood you cannot initialize a repository on remote from local. So I create a repository on remote with a readme file.

[image]

Then I tried pushing local project on to this repository.

1. mkdir MyTestRepo
2. cd MyTestRepo/
3. touch test.txt
4. git init
5. git add .
6. git commit -m "First commit"
7. git remote add origin https://github.com/aniket91/MyTestRepo.git
8. git push -f origin master

[image]

Why did this happen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The force push replaced the history of the remote repo with your local repo.

And your local repo does not include a README.md yet.

A better way would have been a `git pull --rebase` first. Then a git push

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

> As far as I understood you cannot initialize a repository on remote from local.

That depends on what you mean by "initialize".

> ... `git push -f origin master`

This initializes (for some meaning of "initialize") part of a remote repository from the local one.

> Why did this [wipe out my README.md]?

You told the remote "wipe out your existing `master` branch; make your `master` branch point to commit 9288e34 instead."

Without the `-f` (force) flag, you would have *asked* the remote, instead of telling (commanding) it, and it would have said "but if I do that, I will lose 693f1a8", which is the commit that had `README.md` in it.  (It would present this information in the form of a complaint that your push was "not a fast-forward", which is true but not very edifying.)

Answer (score 4):

The readme existed in the remote repo but not locally. Since you didn't pull the remote repo, that readme file was never merged with your local. Instead, the -f flag, "force", overwrote the remote and the readme along with it.